# Why is CORS policy blocking me from loading in HTML snippets from the same folder?

Tags: jquery, cors

I am trying to use the query load() method to load in html from other files into a div.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#president").click(function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#content').load('president.html')
    });
    });
```

Here, I want to load president.html into my content div when a button is pressed. The content div looks like this:

```
 <div class="col-md-7" id = "content">
    </div>
```

When I try to click the button, I get this error in the console:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///UsersKunal/testing/president.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Both files are in the same folder.

Comment: file:// is a different protocol than the allowed ones. A question: are you running that page locally?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up a `localhost` server on your computer using something like [XAMPP on windows](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or [macOS Server on macOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-server/id883878097?mt=12) (alternatively, if you want more control, [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) is good as well).

Reason being that `file://` is not a valid protocol and will be blocked by all browsers, due to previous security issues that the current CORS prevents.

See the documentation at the above sites I referenced for how to set up a proper testing environment, and that will solve your issues.